# How to determine how much variation was due to the differences between a group?

Tags: r, anova, multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

I am working on the data set that consists of Patients (after stroke), Time (then can walk after a going through the program), and Program they follow.

```
Patient   Program   Time
1           P1       12
2           P3       23
3           P3       8
4           P2       36
5           P1       10
```

I am investigating the influence of the program to the results of patients, but I also want to investiagte **how much variation was due to the differences between the patients.**

**My approach** was to consider the Between Group Variation using Anova and Tukey:

```
new <- aov(Patient~Programme, dane)
TukeyHSD(new)
-------------------------------------------
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = Patient ~ Programme, data = dane)

$Programme
                   diff       lwr       upr     p adj
Program2-Program1  2.75 -4.294925  9.794925 0.4682698
Program3-Program1  2.50 -5.634778 10.634778 0.6082676
Program3-Program2 -0.25 -7.294925  6.794925 0.9926869
```

But I think it may not be a good way as it is not clear how much variation between the results was due to the patients.

Summary of anova:

```
> summary(new)                                                                                                     
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Programme    2  10.75   5.375    0.86  0.478
Residuals    5  31.25   6.250
```

**Summary of Time - Programme ANOVA:**

```
summary(new2)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Programme    2  398.4   199.2    0.61   0.58
Residuals    5 1633.5   326.7
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question to display the result of `summary(new)`? That should produce some clues.

Comment: @EdM sure, I edited the question

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I assumed that you were modeling the outcome as a function of `Programme`, as there isn't really anything that can be learned from a regression of an arbitrary numeric patient ID upon `Programme`. Post the anova results of `Time ~ Programme` and I will provide a new answer.

Comment: @EdM I put the summary of Time~Programme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analysis of variance (ANOVA) provides the answer to your specific question. Here, the proper outcome to examine is `Time` in the `Time-Programme` ANOVA.*

The "Residuals" mean square is the variance in `Time` values that isn't accounted for by the modeling of `Programme`. In your case, that residual variance is the variance associated with the patients, while accounting for their different values of `Programme`. The square root of that mean square is about 18, an estimate of the standard deviation among patients under the same `Programme`

An ANOVA significance test evaluates whether the between-treatments mean square is greater than the residual. In your case, it isn't. The modeling of `Programme` didn't "explain" any more variance in `Time` values than there is inherently among patients.

See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/229649/28500) for an introduction to how to think about the mean-square values in a model like yours. Your `Programme` mean square is "MS_between" on that page; your `Residuals` mean square is "MS_within."

A caution: the above assumes that the assumptions underlying ANOVA are reasonably well met. I worry about that for a couple of reasons.

First, the high residual SD (compared against the data values you show) suggests that there might be a lot of skew in the `Time` values, so that (particularly with a small sample as you have) the estimates might not be valid.

Second, with recovery after stroke there might be some who never recover. If so, how do you handle their `Time` values? Whether you just take their values to be the last `Time` at which they were examined or omit those patients from the study, you are making the same mistakes as in improper handling of [censored survival times](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/197628/28500). Your estimates of mean time to recovery will be invalid, probably too low. Unless all of your patients recover function during the time course of your study, you should be using some type of survival analysis.

---

*It's not clear what would be measured by the `Patient~Programme` model, as that just takes what are effectively names (patient ID values) and treats them as numeric outcomes. A simple "re-naming" of patients (exchanging their ID values) would affect those results. The outcome of interest here is `Time`.

Comment: isn't the fact tha 'Patient' is only a unique id to the patient  influence the results of such ANOVA?